# Display Cloudinary React Image based on version

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

I'm looking to find a way to display an image based on the `version` number and `public_id` in React. Something like:

```
<Image
  alt="Project Photo"
  secure="true"
  version="42"
  publicId={publicImageId}>
</Image>
```

Looking through Cloudinary's docs I don't find a mention of a way to accomplish this.

Comment: The code you are using currently should add the version number before the `public_id` when the URL is generated. What is the full URL you get back for the code you shared?